# [C++]Assinging an array a size during constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I'm honestly stuck on how to asssign an array's size during the call of the constructor. Also, I would like the array to be a 'const'. Is this possible during the constructor? Or do I have to do some more tricky stuff? Here is part of the code:

```
class CustomBitmap
{

public:
    CustomBitmap(int width,int height);
    ~CustomBitmap(void);
private:
    const int m_width;
    const int m_height;
    char const m_components[]; 

};
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include "CustomBitmap.h"


CustomBitmap::CustomBitmap(int width,int height) : m_width(width),  m_height(height)
// How do I implement the array? none of the syntax works, I tried m_components([width * height *4]) and all sorts of things along that line.
{}  
CustomBitmap::~CustomBitmap(void) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array has a fixed size (at least in standard C++), so you cannot assign a size to it at runtime, but have to specify its size at compile time.

If you want a variable size, use a `std::vector`, in your case

```
std::vector<char> m_components;
```

If the vector is `const`, then you won't be able to change/append to it, so I don't really see the point of making it `const`, unless you trivially initialize it in class (C++11) as e.g.

```
const std::vector<char> m_components(10, 'a'); // const char vector of 10 a's
```

or

```
const std::vector<char> m_components = {'a','b','c'}; // again C++11 in class initialization
```

You may also do something like

```
template<int N>
class CustomBitmap
{
    ...
   char m_compontents[N];
}
```

but again, this is a template class for which you have to specify the template parameter `N` at compile time, i.e. instantiate it as e.g.

```
CustomBitmap<5> my_custom_bitmap; // now m_components has size 5
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tested it out and it works, you are the best man! :)

Comment: I'm definitely not the best around here, but glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

This kind of syntax:

```
m_components([width * height *4])
```

would be called variable length arrays. VLA. this is C99 norm.
You can't do it here because it exists within your type, which would make the type size itself variable, which is impossible because it is not template.

You can make it template with an integral parameter (rather than `typename` you use `int`) and then you can do what you want.

Howver, you should not do it, because your type will become enormous, which is a bad idea since automatically allocated types can be on the stack, which will explode the limit very quickly and cause a number of inefficiencies since compilers are not used to stack bloat.

You need to allocate on the heap, using `std::vector` is the best answer here. Also be aware for later that `std::array<T,N>` type exists to do what I described in the first paragraph.

Comment: Didn't understand your comment "However, you should not do it, because your type will become enormous". What do you mean? If you use it for 1000 times (with 1000 different sizes) then yes, the object code will instantiate 1000 classes and will become quite large. But otherwise the template solution should be ok to use if you are fine with size specification at compile time.

Comment: the type itself will not grow the binary size, except if it exists in static space ! I am talking about the `sizeof(the type)`.

Comment: Won't it be just `N + sizeof(rest)`? Same as `sizeof(array<char,N>) + sizeof(rest)`? Maybe I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @vsoftco: yes absolutely :) however please check the semantics of what OP is trying to do, he wants to store images ! his `N` will be `height * witdh` in general this is in the millions, do you recommend taking multiple Mega Bytes on the stack ? You know that some devices give you only 24kB of stack space by default. (iOS)